# How do I find out when a tab I've opened with greasemonkey is loaded?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I'm writing a greasemonkey script to go through a list of links and open them in a new tab (reusing the same new tab for all of them), but I can't figure out how to wait until the page has loaded to load the next link... any eventListener I try to add to the new tab gives me a permission denied error... how do I check whether the new tab is fully loaded (or at least loaded enough that the server would have processed the request) or not?  I tried unsafeWindow but also got a denied error with that (I may not fully understand the use though...)

As an example... this is ONE of the multiple things I've tried...

```
mywin.addEventListener(DOMContentLoaded, false);
```

And here's one more (I don't remember what else I tried since I deleted them when they didn't work)........

```
mywin.unsafeWindow.setTimeout(1000);
```

I'm not sure why I was trying to set the timeout on 'mywin' so I'm going to try setting it on the main window, but even if that works I'd still like to know the proper way of checking the status of the new tab.

Thanks!!!

Edit: I did manage to get a setTimeout to work, but it's not the best way since too low a setting means they don't get loaded an a slow connection, and too high a setting means a major delay with a faster connection.

So I'm still looking for a better way!

edit: It *shouldn't* (but might) fall under cross-site/cross-domain scripting as all links are on the same site...

```
starting with 
http://www.aywas.com/message/notices/

the links being opened are like these
http://www.aywas.com/message/notices/9767066/
http://www.aywas.com/message/notices/9765913/
http://www.aywas.com/message/notices/9765644/
```

Edit:
Would GM_xmlhttpRequest or http-on-examine-response possibly work for this?  If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the problem...  oddly enough, I couldn't do it when using `GM_openInTab` to create the window, but using

```
mywin2=window.open("http://www.aywas.com/message/notices/9801049/", "my_win2");
```

allowed me to use the following code to detect the load and close the tab only after it was loaded enough for my purposes! (Although the 'window title' bit of that code above didn't seem to do anything...)

```
mywin2.addEventListener('load', function() {
  mywin2.close()
}, false);
```